# Simulate DELETE Foreign key check

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to simulate the foreign key check that is happening when running DELETE query?

Like if you try to delete an object thats referenced in other table you'd get an error while running a DELETE query. But is there a way to query for all the "dependants" of certain row in a certain table?

Comment: yes, by checking system tables which is different in each dbms

Comment: I know how to find all the FKs for a table but im wondering if theres a way to get all the rows of all the other tables that reference this row

Comment: You can query in sql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15#to-view-the-objects-that-depend-on-a-table

Comment: You could try : `BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE ...;
ROLLBACK;` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but if you want to check if there is reference to a specific row , you can use a query joined with all table that are referenced:

```
select m.pk 
       , case when max(t1.fk) is not null then 1  else 0 end "refrenced in t1"
       , case when max(t2.fk) is not null then 1  else 0 end "refrenced in t2"
from MainTable m
left join childtable1 t1
 on m.pk = t1.fk
left join childtable1 t2
 on m.pk = t2.fk
where m.pk = 10;
group by m.pk
```

if you want to get the rows of the main table and all child tables:

```
select * 
from MainTable m
left join childtable1 t1
 on m.pk = t1.fk
left join childtable1 t2
 on m.pk = t2.fk
where m.pk = 10;
```